# Convergence in probability and distribution relationship

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, statistics, convergence-divergence

$ \color{gray}{\text{I know that convergence in distribution is weaker than convergence in probability, so can I say }} $ $\color{gray}{\text{that the former implies the latter? For example,}}$

$ \color{gray}{\text{Is this}  \ \ X \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(\underline{0}, V^2) \ \Rightarrow \ X \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \underline{0} \ \  \text{statement necessarily true?}}$

Also, if I have $ \ \ Y \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} Z \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(\mu, \Omega^2) \ \ $ Then can I directly claim that:

$ Y \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(\mu, \Omega^2) \ \ $ or do I have to mention $Z$?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

Update:

I was trying to understand the asymptotic normality of the OLS estimator $ \ b = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y  $. The problem that I encountered:

The regression model is $ \ y_i \ = \ \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_{i2} + \cdots + \beta_k x_{ik} + e_i \ $ or written as $ \ \underset{n \times 1}{Y} \ = \ \underset{n \times k}{X} \underset{k \times 1}{\beta} + \underset{n \times 1}{e} \ $.

Now, we have

$ b \ = \ \beta \ + \ \left(  X'X \right)^{-1}  X'e$

and we know that

$ \frac{\ 1 \ }{n} X'X \  \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}  \ Q \hspace{.5em}  $  which is a positive definite (and symmetric) matrix.

$ \frac{\ 1 \ }{n} X'e \  \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \ \underline{0} $

If I was given the following

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n} }  X'e \ \overset{ d }{\longrightarrow} \ N(\underline{0}, \ \sigma^2 Q) $

How can I show that

$ \sqrt[]{n} (b - \beta)  \ \overset{ d }{\longrightarrow} \ N(\underline{0}, \ \sigma^2 Q^{-1}) $

---

My attempt:

$ \sqrt[]{n} (b - \beta) \ = \ \left( \frac{1}{n}  X'X \right)^{-1}  \ \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}} X'e \ \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}  \ Q^{-1} \ \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}} X'e \ \overset{ d }{\longrightarrow} \ N(\underline{0}, \ \sigma^2 Q^{-1}) $

so that $ \sqrt[]{n} (b - \beta) \ \overset{ d }{\longrightarrow} \ N(\underline{0}, \ \sigma^2 Q^{-1}) $

But I have no idea if my steps above make any mathematical sense... If not, what would be the correct way of obtaining the result? Thank you!

Comment: If convergence in distribution is *weaker* than convergence in probability then this means there will be cases where the former does not lead to  the latter

Comment: @Henry Thank you! I confused weaker with stronger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

- $\frac{1}{n} X'X \overset{p}{\to} Q$ where $Q$ is non-random. By the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), $\left(\frac{1}{n} X'X\right)^{-1} \overset{p}{\to} Q^{-1}$.
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X'e \overset{d}{\to} U$ where $U \sim N(0, \sigma^2 Q)$.

[Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) then implies
$$\left(\frac{1}{n} X'X\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X'e\right)
\overset{d}{\to} Q^{-1} U.$$
Finally, note that $Q^{-1} U$ is a linear transformation of a Gaussian vector with mean $Q^{-1} 0 = 0$ and covariance $Q^{-1} (\sigma^2 Q) (Q^{-1})^\top = \sigma^2 Q^{-1}$, so $Q^{-1} U \sim N(0, \sigma^2 Q^{-1})$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!